# How to identify an app in iphone from desktop

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, mobile, itunes

When I connect my iPhone to desktop (say windows 7), I need to identify if a specific app is installed in my iPhone or not through my own application running in desktop.

How to do this?

I tried searching in internet, but could not find. Can iTune database will be of any help for this?

I could see the similar thing is done by iExplorer (http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/), but not able to figure out how to do!

please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use iTunes to get the details of all the applications installed on your iphone.

Comment: yes that's true. I like to get this detail in my own program running in desktop. I will edit the question as well for clarity

Comment: What exactly are you seeking to know ?? Is it like you are trying to see if the app developed by you is installed on iPhone..? or is it that you are trying to create a desktop application to get the apps installed on your iPhone ??

Comment: I am trying to create a desktop application to get the apps installed on my iPhone

Comment: I guess that is possible only if you create an iOS app and have that installed on the phone and with that app you can trigger the data (list of apps) to your desktop application..

Comment: I installed http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/ , and it is able to get all the apps installed on my iPhone.. not sure how they did!.. i guess they read it somewhere through iTunes app that is installed in my computer.